# What is Kumomadori Radio?

Tags: nichijou, arawi-keiichi

So in December 2018, Arawi Keiichi (creator of Nichijou) [announced](https://twitter.com/himaraya/status/1077888915497922561) another Kumomadori Radio:

[image: 今年もやりまお！12月28日（金) 24:00~ (さよなら平成）kumomadoriラジオ]

(It was then [delayed](https://twitter.com/himaraya/status/1078043722078597120) due to what appears to be scheduling difficulties.)

But what is Kumomadori Radio? I keep seeing mentions of it in Nichijou-related blog posts, but it's not clear what exactly it is.